Why does my form script error out after correctly setting Title?
I have a Google script trying to populate a question for a Google form:
const form = FormApp.openById(FORM_ID);
form.getItemById(1697670046).setTitle("What is your first name?");

The question gets populated in the form but then I immediately get the error...

Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property setTitle on object FormApp.Item.

...and the script stops.
I have zero idea what I'm doing wrong. How can I resolve this exception please?
EDIT- This is happening on numerous forms that used to work up until last week.  Did something change with the syntax?

The script may be stopping, but I think you'll find that the title is updated.

The question doesn't describe the item type, but lets assume that it is  "Multiple choice". Try this instead form.getItemById(1697670046).asMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("What is your first name?"). This should run without an error and should update the title as well.

Thank you for the response! I don't know why, but as of last week this line of code worked without ".asMultipleChoiceItem()".  I was able to distinguish the type in a different line when I was setting the choices.  Again, thank you!
